# ConTeXt: Conditional check of text with dollar symbols

Tags: equations, context, xml

## Background

An XML document contains TeX elements in inline- and paragraph forms:

```xml
<p>Inline: <tex>$E=mc^3$</tex></p>
<p><tex>$$E=mc^2$$</tex></p>
```

I'd like to conditionally use [placeformula](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/placeformula) with a cross-reference when `$$` starts the `<tex>` element.

### System

ConTeXt version: 2023.09.26 18:19

## Problem

Everything I've tried to extract the first characters ends up with a compile failure.

## Code

Here's the base setup:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:tex
  \xmlflushcontext{#1}
\stopxmlsetups
```

This works to generate the document, obviously without a cross-reference. Here are some attempts to obtain the leading characters (all failed):

```tex
\getfirstcharacter{\xmltext{#1}{.}}
\firstcharacter
% ...

\getfirstcharacter{\expanded{\xmlverbatim{#1}}}
\firstcharacter
% ...

\getfirstcharacter{\xmlflush{#1}}
\firstcharacter
% ...

\thefirstcharacter{\xmlflush{#1}}
\firstcharacter
% ...

\setvariable{Reference}{xml}{\xmlflush{#1}}
\getvariable{Reference}{xml}

\doiffirstcharelse{\xmlflush{#1}}{\textdollar}{DOLLAR}{NO DOLLAR}
\doiffirstcharelse{\xmltext{#1}}{\textdollar}{DOLLAR}{NO DOLLAR}
```

Plus numerous variations thereof. Using `doiffirstcharelse` won't work because I need to check the first two characters (or a substring), but gets the idea across.

## Question

How would you extract the content of the XML `tex` element and check for a double-dollar sign to conditionally apply separate commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\doifinstringelse` combined with `\getsubstring` appears to work:

```tex
\startbuffer[main]
<body>
    <p>Inline: <tex>$E=mc^3$</tex></p>
    <p><tex>$$E=mc^2$$</tex></p>
</body>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:root
    \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:root}

\startxmlsetups xml:body
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
    \xmlflush{#1}
    \par
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:tex
    \doifinstringelse%
        {$$}% Pattern
        {\getsubstring{1}{2}{\xmlflushcontext{#1}}}% Text
        {True}% True code
        {False}% False code

    \xmlflushcontext{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startTEXpage[offset=1dk, width=3in, align=middle]
    \xmlprocessbuffer{main}{main}{}
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

I found these commands by searching for "string" in the [command reference manual](https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf).

Comment: @DaveJarvis The hacky solution would be to replace `\xmlflushcontext{#1}` with `\catcode\`$=9\relax\xmlpure{#1}`; a better solution would be to filter the `tex` tags with Lua

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, Max. Much appreciated. https://gitlab.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/-/blob/main/xhtml/xml-tex.tex